# Spring Boot RabbitMQ attempt to deserialize unauthorized class exception

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I use RabbitMQ in a Spring Boot project:

`sender`

```java
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UserSender {

    private final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    public String send() {
        User user = new User(1L, "Tom", "123");
        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("userQueue", user);
        return "user sender sent: " + user;
    }
}
```

`Receiver`

```java
@Component
public class UserReceiver {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "userQueue")
    @RabbitHandler
    private void process(User user) {
        System.out.println("received user: " + user);
    }
}
```

When startup there is an exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Attempt to deserialize unauthorized class com.example.lab06.entity.User; add allowed class name patterns to the message converter or, if you trust the message orginiator, set environment variable 'SPRING_AMQP_DESERIALIZATION_TRUST_ALL' or system property 'spring.amqp.deserialization.trust.all' to true
```

I checked the [Spring AMPQ Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#json-message-converter)

> You can set the patterns using the `allowedListPatterns` property on these converters. Alternatively, if you trust all message originators, you can set the environment variable `SPRING_AMQP_DESERIALIZATION_TRUST_ALL` or system property `spring.amqp.deserialization.trust.all` to `true`.

However, I can not set `spring.amqp.deserialization.trust.all` in `application.properties`. I get this error:

```
Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.amqp.deserialization.trust.all'
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Can you include the code for the User class?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation states (emphasis mine):

> ...set the **environment variable** `SPRING_AMQP_DESERIALIZATION_TRUST_ALL` or **system property** `spring.amqp.deserialization.trust.all` to `true`.

The values configured in `application.properties` are *not* environment variables or system properties. Environment variables are set in your environment and system properties are typically passed to the JVM as `-D` parameters.

Therefore, you need to set `spring.amqp.deserialization.trust.all` as a **system property** in whatever way is appropriate for your use case.

It's worth noting that this setting essentially circumvents the security check when deserializing messages and may leave your application vulnerable to remote attacks. You're recommended to set the patterns using the `allowedListPatterns` property on the converter.

Answer (score 1):

thanks @Bertram，here is my solution by using `setTrustedPackages`:

```java
@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonToMapMessageConverter() {
        DefaultClassMapper defaultClassMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
        defaultClassMapper.setTrustedPackages("YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME"); // trusted packages
        Jackson2JsonMessageConverter jackson2JsonMessageConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
        jackson2JsonMessageConverter.setClassMapper(defaultClassMapper);
        return jackson2JsonMessageConverter;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the `allowedListPatterns` property on the converter:

```java
    @Bean
    public SimpleMessageConverter converter() {
        SimpleMessageConverter converter = new SimpleMessageConverter();
        converter.setAllowedListPatterns(List.of("xyz.test.common.*", "java.util.*"));
        return converter;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This need for `allowedListPatterns` is due to CVE-2023-34050 Spring AMQP Deserialization Vulnerability. See: https://spring.io/security/cve-2023-34050

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).